# Top2Vec model (>100MB) doesn't load on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, joblib

I have a Python Flask app on Heroku. There are 3 [Top2Vec](https://github.com/ddangelov/Top2Vec) trained models that I'm trying to load as global variables in `app.py`, before first request:

```
@app.before_first_request
def models():
  global model1
  global model2
  global model3
  model1, model2, model3 = load_models()
```

`load_models()` method, just the standard load call defined in the Top2Vec library:

```
def load_models():
return [Top2Vec.load(MODEL1_PATH), Top2Vec.load(MODEL2_PATH),
        Top2Vec.load(MODEL3_PATH)]
```

where `MODEL1_PATH`, `MODEL2_PATH`, `MODEL3_PATH`are the absolute path to the model file.

When I try to open the app localy, everything works fine, but when I open the hosted web app, I get:

[image]

All three models are files **larger than 100MB** and are uploaded with `git lfs` and I suspect, this might play a role in the error I'm getting. Any ideas why I'm getting this and how to fix it? Am I making some rookie mistake?

Comment: Yes it's due to lfs settings, this is the solution: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-nlp-model-on-heroku-using-flask-nltk-and-git-lfs-eed7d1b22b11